# XSD 1.1: attribute has same values than other attributes

Tags: xml, xsd, attributes

I am supposed to design a card-game in xml, using xsd 1.1. Each card has an element "type" which also defines a color as well as an element "annotation" which can have several attributes, for example "function" and "until" (like in the example):

```
<card>
   <type color="black">One</type>
   <annotation function="drawcards">1</annotation>
</card>
```

For some of these cards I am supposed to define the attribute "until" as a sort of condition that should be fullfilled and can only have the same values as the attributes "color" or "function". The first both attributes are determined by enumerations and can only have certain values:

```
    <xs:simpleType name="color">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="black"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="red"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="blue"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="green"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="function">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="drawcards"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="cancel_turn"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="reverse"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="throwcards"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
```

How do I define it in an xsd-file that the attribute "until" can only have a value that is similar to one of the values from "function" or "color"? Do I need to set up a list that has all the same values or is there a shorter way of doing it?

==EDIT:==

As requested, here is a full XML and XSD with an assertion that was supposed to do the trick. However it is not working - the compiler always throws an error:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cards xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='TestAttribute.xsd'>
    
    <card>
        <type color="black">One</type>
        <annotation function="drawcards">1</annotation>
    </card> 
    
    <card>
        <type color="black">Two</type>
        <annotation function="throwcards">2</annotation>
    </card> 
    
    <card>
        <type color="black">Three</type>
        <annotation function="drawcards" until="black">1</annotation>
    </card> 
    
    <card>
        <type color="black">Five</type>
        <annotation function="reverse" until="red">1</annotation>
    </card> 
</cards>
```

XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" elementFormDefault="qualified" vc:minVersion="1.1"> 
<xs:element name="cards">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="card" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="type">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:simpleContent>
                                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:attribute name="color" use="required">
                                             <xs:simpleType>
                                                 <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                                     <xs:enumeration value="black"/>
                                                     <xs:enumeration value="red"/>
                                                     <xs:enumeration value="blue"/>
                                                     <xs:enumeration value="green"/>
                                                 </xs:restriction>
                                             </xs:simpleType>
                                         </xs:attribute>
                                    </xs:extension>                                                                      
                                </xs:simpleContent>
                            </xs:complexType>                            
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="annotation">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:simpleContent>
                                    <xs:extension base="xs:integer">
                                        <xs:attribute name="function" use="required">
                                            <xs:simpleType>
                                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                                    <xs:enumeration value="drawcards"/>
                                                    <xs:enumeration value="cancel_turn"/>
                                                    <xs:enumeration value="reverse"/>
                                                    <xs:enumeration value="throwcards"/>
                                                </xs:restriction>
                                            </xs:simpleType>
                                        </xs:attribute>
                                        <xs:attribute name="until"/>
                                        <xs:assert test="if (@until) then (@until = type/@color) or (@until = annotation/@function) else not (@until)"/>
                                    </xs:extension>
                                </xs:simpleContent>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use an assertion such as `<xs:assert test="@until = type/@color or @until = annotation/@function"/>`

(However, I don't know if this is precisely the constraint you are describing; using words such as "a sort of condition" and "a value that is similar to" suggests a level of fuzziness in your requirements...)

== LATER ==

Now that we can see your schema and instance document: the assertion should be defined on the `card` element (because that's where all the data needed by the assertion is "in scope") and it should then address the relevant data from that context:

`<xs:assert test="annotation/@until = type/@color or annotation/@until = annotation/@function"/>`

or more concisely

`<xs:assert test="annotation/@until = (type/@color, annotation/@function)"/>`

Comment: Thank you for confirming that it is not only me who is struggeling with this task.
I tried your solution but sadly it is not working as supposed because the assertion always fails no matter which value "until" has (Error 129).

Comment: Is there a message associated with "Error 129"? What schema processor are you using? If you add a complete XML and XSD, then I can help you diagnose it.

Comment: I'm working with Oxygen XML Editor, latest version. The error message displayed is:  cvc-assertion: Assertion evaluation ('if (@until) then (@until = type/@color) or (@until = annotation/@function) else not (@until)') for element 'annotation' on schema type '#AnonType_annotationcardcards' did not succeed..

Comment: Have edited the question as you suggested with the full XML and XSD

Comment: And thank you very much for your answer. The assert was indeed misplaced. After fixing that everything is now working as supposed!

Comment: Sorry again - I need to ask how do I do it that the attribute until can have any of the values of the attribute color or function?
Right now it only succeeds when it has the same value as the attribute (so only when color='black" and until='black' it is correct but not when color='black' and until='red').

Comment: At this point it's probably a good idea to ask a new question.

Comment: Okay. Did it here now:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65637303/xsd-1-1-attribute-is-supposed-to-only-have-values-of-another-attribute